# sshd block access from some host names

Tags: ssh, synology

I want to block access from some external host to my ssh deamon. Is there something in the sshd_config file I can set?

Just if this matters: I'm on a Synology 1010+ with openssh installed from ipgk, if this matters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do this by adding the following to your sshd_config

DenyUsers username@host

for example when you want to ssh acces from the 80.25 ip-range for root:

> DenyUsers root@80.25.*

From the manpages:

> The allow/deny directives are processed in the following order: DenyUsers, AllowUsers, DenyGroups, and finally AllowGroups.

Comment: Of course, the best thing to do is set up iptables rules, though I don't know if that is possible. It seems that `DenyUsers` also supports wildcards for the username, so `DenyUsers *@80.25.*` would be the way to block everyone from 80.25.